# Undefined method 'config' for ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to follow several tutorials to connect Rails 5 in API mode with Ember application but in all of them once I create new initializer and use:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json
```

I get "undefined method 'config' for ActiveModel::Serializer ..." I am using 'active_model_serializer' gem since Ember expects a json with a root object instead of plain json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

instead of

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json
```

Please read more on [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md)

In Gemfile

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesn't work. Now I get "uninitialized constant ActiveModelSerializers", I have added the gem without the version number should I also add version number or it should work only with gem name?

Comment: in gemfile please add `gem 'active_model_serializers'` do not require any version but which version are you using it will install the latest one

Comment: It is already added. Don't know why it's not getting the class

Comment: can you please try `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi`

Comment: please do `bundle show active_model_serializers` and put the output

Comment: "/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/active_model_serializers-0.9.3

Comment: ok got please try in Gemfile `gem 'active_model_serializers', github: rails-api/active_model_serializers` then bundle install and then try